# Is it possible to browse the apps available for the Apple TV device with a web browser on a desktop?

Tags: ios-appstore, appletv

I want to avoid typing with the Apple TV Remote and use the keyboard of my desktop pc to search apps. On Apple'S web page they explain what the app store is but I cannot find a way to browse apps there. Looks like one can only browse apps that are available for a device after buying that device and on that device.

Or is there a way?

(Are there other forums targeting Apple TV? Is my tag ios-appstore right, is apple tv running an ios version at all?)

Comment: Found this [suggestion in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/g8snzz/is_there_any_way_to_browse_the_ios_app_store_on_pc/) - fnd.io seems to work.

Comment: @MrR perfect, thx. happy to take this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this reddit thread on web alternatives to app store](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/g8snzz/is_there_any_way_to_browse_the_ios_app_store_on_pc/) -

> This doesn’t work for you?
>
> https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/
>
> If it doesn’t, you can use this but it’s 3rd party
>
> http://fnd.io/

[image: find.io search page]

Comment: The app-store links leads to an overview pagfe, but no chance to search for apps there. thx